# how to get the links from this page?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

There are some data on this page :

```
$ scrapy shell 'https://www.catalogs.ssg.asia/toyota/?lang=en#bWFya2V0PT1nZW5lcmFsfHxzdD09MjB8fHN0cz09eyIxMCI6IlJlZ2lvbiIsIjIwIjoiTWlkZGxlIEVhc3QifQ%3D%3D'
```

I cannot scrape the urls from this table, each time I try to select it with this, I get an empty set.

> response.css('tr[class=over]').extract()

Comment: Required table is not present in initial page source, but generated dynamically. I'm not sure that you can use `scrapy` in this case. Try to get data with `selenium`. You should also pay more attention to quality of your questions. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get more good answers...

Answer (score 0):

Use `view(response)` to open the HTML that scrapy downloaded on your computer, and you will find there is no table.

scrapy only return the HTML code, when the data is generated by JavaScript, it will not returned by scrapy.